# Performance issue of measureText

Tags: android, performance

I have a performance problem in some code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){        \\ size ~ 30k
    String str = list.get(i);
    float strWidth = paint.measureText (str);
}
```

my android app is freezing for a 5 seconds in Genymotion emulator, but when i do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){        \\ size ~ 30k
    String str = list.get(i);

    str = "a very very very long string";
    float strWidth = paint.measureText (str);
}
```

I have not any performance problems at all. How can explain this? Help please.
In paint i use custom fonts.

I have tried the multithreaded processing. I created 10, 100 threads for the list, each thread processed some part of list. But i always get the same result (5 seconds or more). I used AsyncTask.

Comment: what is a list ? an ArrayList ?

Comment: Did you test this on real Device.

Comment: Yes, it is array list. And app works in real device for a 50 seconds.

Comment: you dont find any performance problems in second approach is because java strings are immutable and to they are stored in string pool for caching. you are not changing string in second loop and thus it is not storing a new string and won't waste time in calculating its attributes. I am not sure about performance alternatives for measureText() but making it multi-threaded and lazy loading can be the options. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I tried StringBuilder and multithreading. It does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternate way for improving performance,

```
String str;
float strWidth;
int size = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){        
    str = list.get(i);
    strWidth = paint.measureText (str);
}
```

Everytime accessing `list.size()` in for loop is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In the latter case the string does not change, so the result gets cached somewhere and does not reevaluate.

If `paint.measureText` is not cheap, you can measure only strings with a large number of letters. You can speed things up 10x-100x easily if you can live with the possibility of imprecise result.

I would

1. Find longest string (according to number of letters)
2. Measure only strings whose number of letters is at least 70% of the longest